# Spring boot run error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

The project spring boot 1..5.7 release. I am using Intellij IDEA 2017.2.4 and gradle for dependency management. When i build the project it builds successfully with no error. When I run the application with bootRun gradle task it shows the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener : org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getRunListeners(SpringApplication.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:291)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.kifiya.lmanagement.LmanagementApplication.main(LmanagementApplication.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:409)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.(EventPublishingRunListener.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: did you resolved it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a dependency problem within Spring, as it's mentioned above. The easiest way IMHO is to check your POM file.

Check out here for more info: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html

Comment: No pom file in the project. It is a gradle spring boot project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `spring-aop` doesn't match the rest of your libraries. Try running `gradle dependencies` and check that all Spring dependencies are in the same version. More on inspecting dependencies in [Gradle User Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#inspecting_dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same error after converting a Spring application to Spring Boot. Using the `spring-boot-starter-aop` instead of a direct dependency on a specific version of `spring-aop` resolved it for me, e.g. in `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {

    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.17.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop' 

}
```

instead of

```
dependencies {

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.2.4.RELEASE'
}
```